# how to set dynamic height for all iphone screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

In my application dn't use autolayout and size classes. Create all the elements programmatically.

Calculate view width and set frame for each element. Here my code.

```
 UILabel* TitleLbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((self.view.frame.size.width/2)-25,(self.view.frame.size.height/2)-235,100, 50)];
    TitleLbl.text=@"Login";
    TitleLbl.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    TitleLbl.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14.0];
    [self.view addSubview:TitleLbl];


    //NSLog(@"ttttt %@",(self.view.frame.size.height/10));

    UILabel* AccountLbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((self.view.frame.size.width/2)-130,(self.view.frame.size.height/2)-210,350, 50)];
    AccountLbl.text=@"Login or Create Your New Account";
    AccountLbl.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    AccountLbl.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16.0];
    [self.view addSubview:AccountLbl];


    UITextField* UserNameFld = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x+40, (self.view.frame.size.height/2)-175,self.view.frame.size.width-80, 40)];
    UserNameFld.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
    UserNameFld.placeholder = @"Username";
    UserNameFld.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    NSAttributedString *str = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Username" attributes:@{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor colorWithRed:244.0f/255.0f green:244.0f/255.0f blue:244.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0] }];
    UserNameFld.attributedPlaceholder = str;
    UserNameFld.delegate = self;
    [self DrawLine: UserNameFld];
    [self.view addSubview:UserNameFld];

    UITextField* PassWorldFld = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x+40, (self.view.frame.size.height/2)-135,self.view.frame.size.width-80, 40)];
    PassWorldFld.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
    PassWorldFld.placeholder = @"Password";
    PassWorldFld.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
     PassWorldFld.secureTextEntry = YES;
    PassWorldFld.delegate = self;
    NSAttributedString *strPassword = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Password" attributes:@{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor colorWithRed:244.0f/255.0f green:244.0f/255.0f blue:244.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0] }];
    PassWorldFld.attributedPlaceholder = strPassword;
    [self DrawLine: PassWorldFld];
    [self.view addSubview:PassWorldFld];


    UIButton *ForPassBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    //    [ForPassBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(aMethod:)
    //     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [ForPassBtn setTitle:@"Forgot Password?" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    ForPassBtn.frame = CGRectMake((self.view.frame.size.width/2), (self.view.frame.size.height/2)-90, (self.view.frame.size.width/2)-40, 20.0);
    ForPassBtn.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    ForPassBtn.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentRight;
    ForPassBtn.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13.0];
    ForPassBtn.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    [self.view addSubview:ForPassBtn];





    UIButton *LoginBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
//    [LoginBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(aMethod:)
//     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [LoginBtn setTitle:@"Login" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    LoginBtn.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x+40,(self.view.frame.size.height/2)-65, self.view.frame.size.width-80, 30.0);
    LoginBtn.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
    LoginBtn.layer.borderWidth=1.0f;
    LoginBtn.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    LoginBtn.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;
    LoginBtn.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0];
    [self.view addSubview:LoginBtn];
```

How can i calulate the dynamic heigth for this code. 
Any one can help me. how to calulate dynamic heigth. give any solution for me. Thanks advance.

Comment: are you want to set the dynamic heigt for your VIewcontroller

Comment: this code want to become dynamic height for all view and screen size ipad iphone universal app.

Comment: all view means , your butin textfiled or self.view

Comment: yes.. added in self.view.. all views saying all device screen.

Comment: are you speak tamil . if yes konjam theliva solriya

Answer (score 2):

Write below in .pch file

```
#define iPhoneFactorX ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width*1.00/1080.0)
```

Now write a code as per screen size of 1080x1920

E.g. you want to set a UIImage of size 600*400

```
UIImageView *m1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(240*iPhoneFactorX, 100*iPhoneFactorX, 600*iPhoneFactorX, 400*iPhoneFactorX)];
```

Below is how I calculate starting point as `240`

```
(1080-600)/2
      ^^^ width of image
```

This make 1 code for all screens....

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik : did you get what I am doing?

Comment: Good.It is simple way.

Answer (score 1):

```
UILabel* TitleLbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((self.view.frame.size.width/2)-25,(self.view.frame.size.height/2)-235,100, 50)];
TitleLbl.text=@"Login";
TitleLbl.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
TitleLbl.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14.0];
[self.view addSubview:TitleLbl];


//NSLog(@"ttttt %@",(self.view.frame.size.height/10));

UILabel* AccountLbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((self.view.frame.size.width/2)-130,TitleLbl.frame.origin.y + TitleLbl.frame.size.height + 10,350, 50)];
AccountLbl.text=@"Login or Create Your New Account";
AccountLbl.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
AccountLbl.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16.0];
[self.view addSubview:AccountLbl];


UITextField* UserNameFld = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x+40, AccountLbl.frame.origin.y + AccountLbl.frame.size.height + 10,self.view.frame.size.width-80, 40)];
UserNameFld.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
UserNameFld.placeholder = @"Username";
UserNameFld.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
NSAttributedString *str = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Username" attributes:@{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor colorWithRed:244.0f/255.0f green:244.0f/255.0f blue:244.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0] }];
UserNameFld.attributedPlaceholder = str;
UserNameFld.delegate = self;
//  [self DrawLine: UserNameFld];
[self.view addSubview:UserNameFld];

UITextField* PassWorldFld = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(UserNameFld.frame.origin.x, UserNameFld.frame.origin.y + UserNameFld.frame.size.height + 10,UserNameFld.frame.origin.x + UserNameFld.frame.size.width, 40)];
PassWorldFld.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
PassWorldFld.placeholder = @"Password";
PassWorldFld.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
PassWorldFld.secureTextEntry = YES;
PassWorldFld.delegate = self;
NSAttributedString *strPassword = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Password" attributes:@{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor colorWithRed:244.0f/255.0f green:244.0f/255.0f blue:244.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0] }];
PassWorldFld.attributedPlaceholder = strPassword;
 // [self DrawLine: PassWorldFld];
[self.view addSubview:PassWorldFld];


UIButton *ForPassBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
//    [ForPassBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(aMethod:)
//     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[ForPassBtn setTitle:@"Forgot Password?" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
ForPassBtn.frame = CGRectMake((self.view.frame.size.width/2), PassWorldFld.frame.origin.y + PassWorldFld.frame.size.height + 50, (self.view.frame.size.width/2)-40, 20.0);
ForPassBtn.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
ForPassBtn.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentRight;
ForPassBtn.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13.0];
ForPassBtn.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
[self.view addSubview:ForPassBtn];





UIButton *LoginBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
//    [LoginBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(aMethod:)
//     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[LoginBtn setTitle:@"Login" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
LoginBtn.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x+40,ForPassBtn.frame.origin.y + ForPassBtn.frame.size.height + 50, self.view.frame.size.width-80, 30.0);
LoginBtn.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
LoginBtn.layer.borderWidth=1.0f;
LoginBtn.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
LoginBtn.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;
LoginBtn.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0];
[self.view addSubview:LoginBtn];
```

Comment: We should try above like that.